# Assigning object retrieved by Parse.Query to a variable

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be incredibly simple but have been searching for hours on end with no luck. I simply want to query a subclass of Parse.Object for a given objectId (ideally using .get() but .find or .first could work too) and assign that entire object to a variable I can access outside of the query. I understand that queries return promises and I am able to log the object I want to capture from inside of my .then() function but I can't figure out how to access it elsewhere. Here's what I have right now and I think I am on the right track.

```
      var thisLunchQuery = new Parse.Query(Lunch);
      var lunchIdTemp = this.model.get("lunchId");

      thisLunchQuery.equalTo("objectId", lunchIdTemp);
      var thisLunch = thisLunchQuery.find().then(function(results) {
        console.log(results[0]);
      });
```

This logs the entire object I want to access and I can see it's properties in the console. However, I would like to be able to access the "thisLunch" variable elsewhere in my code. As it stands, I can't do that. I'm assuming that's because of the scope of the variable. How can I define that variable in such a way that it gets a bigger scope

Here's a more comprehensive peace of code showing what I'm trying to do

```
render: function() {

  var thisLunchQuery = new Parse.Query(Lunch);
  var lunchIdTemp = this.model.get("lunchId");

  function assignLunch(results){
    //not sure what goes here
  }

  thisLunchQuery.equalTo("objectId", lunchIdTemp);
  thisLunch = thisLunchQuery.find().then(assignLunch);


  var templateArgs ={
    thisPlans: this.model.toJSON(),
    thisLunch: thisLunch
  };


  $(this.el).html(this.template(templateArgs));
  return this;
  this.delegateEvents();
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to grab the object so I can pass it in to a template and access its attributes there. I hope this helps, I'm pretty new to all of this.

UPDATE:

Here's my best attempt at trying to chain queries so that I can use part of the result from the first one as a parameter for a second one and then use both queried for objects in the final callback function.

```
render: function() {

  var thisLunchQuery = new Parse.Query(Lunch);
  var thisLocationQuery = new Parse.Query(Location);
  var lunchIdTemp = this.model.get("lunchId");

  function assignLunch(results){
    lunchObject = results[0];
    thisLocationQuery.equalTo("objectId",    results[0].get("locationId");
thisLocationQuery.find.then(assignLocation);
  }

function assignLocation(locationResults, lunchObject){
// I'd like to be able to access the location I just found (locationResults[0]) as 
//well as the original lunchId from the first query inside this callback

var templateArgs ={
    thisPlans: this.model.toJSON(),
    thisLunch: lunchObject,
    thisLocation: locationResults[0];
  };

  $(this.el).html(this.template(templateArgs));
}

  thisLunchQuery.equalTo("objectId", lunchIdTemp);
  thisLunch = thisLunchQuery.find().then(assignLunch);

  return this;
  this.delegateEvents();
}
```

Obviously this doesn't quiet work but I'm not sure how to pass along data like I'm trying to. Maybe I should be using .when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is define a function that does what you want to do with your results, and pass it to the promise success method. Could look like this:

```
function doSomething(result) {
// do your stuff here
}

thisLunchQuery.find().then(doSomething)
```

#### UPDATE:

In the context of your view, the code could look something like:

```
render: function() {

  var thisLunchQuery = new Parse.Query(Lunch);
  var lunchIdTemp = this.model.get("lunchId");

  var self = this;
  function assignLunch(results){
    var templateArgs = {
      thisPlans: this.model.toJSON(),
      thisLunch: results
    };
    self.$el.html(self.template(templateArgs));
  }

  thisLunchQuery.equalTo("objectId", lunchIdTemp);
  thisLunchQuery.find().then(assignLunch);

  return this;
}
```

Comment: How do I use this to assign my result object to a variable? When I console.log(result[0]) inside of the doSomething function, it prints the correct object but I still don't think that gives me the desired result. When I return result[0] in doSomething and then do thisLunch = thisLunchQuery.find().then(doSomething), thisLunch still holds a promise, not an object.

Comment: this is async programming. `thisLunch` will not have the value your function returns when it executed, because that values is computed async and not available by the time of the variable assignment. This is why we are handling the results in a callback function.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm new to async and having trouble wrapping my head around it. I thought the point of .then was to wait until the query is finished and then do something with the result. Like I said, result[0] holds the object I'm trying to capture inside my callback function. Is it at all possible to make that object reachable outside of that function? I eventually want to pass it to a new template declaration.

Comment: You can easily assign it to a variable outside of the function scope. your problem then will be to know when does the value get assigned to that variable, so you relay on a callback regardless in order to move on. at that point, it stops making sense to try and handle variables outside the scope of a function and you its better to handle things in a more functional fashion. If you posted a concrete example of what you are trying to accomplish I could give you a concrete example on how you could approach it in a "functional" way

Comment: Awesome, that is working for what I originally wanted to do. I think I've come across one more layer of complexity I'm stumped on. How would I go about running another query that uses the result of the first one as a parameter and then allows me access both the new result, as well as the old one in the new callback function. I'm going to mark this as an answer because it certainly answer the original question but I'll add code describing this new issue if you're able to help.

Comment: if you are already using backbone, the idea is to put data in models, and listen to change events on the model, so you render upon model changes, not upon data sync with the server.

Comment: I get the idea of rendering on changes, but the purpose of this code is to show an initial list of data from a link table (and the objects it links) so the user can interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either call a function with thisLunch as a parameter like:

```
  var thisLunchQuery = new Parse.Query(Lunch);
  var lunchIdTemp = this.model.get("lunchId");

  thisLunchQuery.equalTo("objectId", lunchIdTemp);
  var thisLunch = thisLunchQuery.find().then(function(results) {
     funcName(results[0])
  });
```

or put it in the global/window object like:

```
  var thisLunchQuery = new Parse.Query(Lunch);
  var lunchIdTemp = this.model.get("lunchId");

  thisLunchQuery.equalTo("objectId", lunchIdTemp);
  var thisLunch = thisLunchQuery.find().then(function(results) {
     window.myLunch = results[0];
  });
```

Comment: I seem to be having trouble getting either of these options to work. Do either of them require me to get rid of the "var thisLunch =" in front of the thiisLunchQuery.find()? Also, what would the code inside funcName look like and what does myLunch refer to?